# alternate for deprecated methods in ES org.elasticsearch.action.delete.DeleteRequest

Tags: elasticsearch, deprecated, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I am using org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.13.2 as elasticsearch dependency as all the previous versions are quarantined in my organization.

However, am now facing deployment issues due to sonarlint failure on the deprecated methods like
`org.elasticsearch.action.delete.DeleteRequest`
`org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest`
`org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateRequest`

Is there an alternative for the above functions to create/update/delete documents in ES. I did search for this topic but could not find a solution.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware of, only multiple argument constructors are deprecated, the default one and the one with index as an argument can still be used.

```
    @Deprecated
    public IndexRequest(String index, String type) {
        super(NO_SHARD_ID);
        this.index = index;
        this.type = type;
    }

    
    public IndexRequest(String index) {
        super(NO_SHARD_ID);
        this.index = index;
    }
```

This may be a dumb suggestion but have you tried using the non-deprecated constructors?